# If $xy=x^{-1}y^{-1}$, does this imply $x=x^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This seems like a simple enough question, trying to show that if the title condition holds, that a group $G$ of which $x,y$ are elements, then $G$ is Abelian.
$$xy=x^{-1}y^{-1}=(yx)^{-1}$$
From here I could say, Let $yx=z$.  $z\in G$ since $G$ is closed, which means that the final thing I need is to show that $z^{-1}=z$.  But isn't that implied in the title condition?

Comment: You need the phrase "for all $x,y$ in $G$." "... of which $x,y$ elements, in English, means that $x,y$ are specific elements of $G$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $xy=x^{-1}y^{-1}$ for all $x,y\in G$, then specifically  $x=x^{-1}$ for all $x\in G$ (just let $y=e$)

Comment: Therefore, $(yx)^{-1}=yx$.  Awesome.  I thought so, but setting $y=e$, I just didn't even consider that!  Thanks!

Comment: One small additional comment (which you may already know): in a group $G$ where $x = x^{-1}$ for all $a \in G$, this means every element has order 2. It is now a simple exercise to show that such a group is abelian.